# Is it possible to cast this to a different type for the entire function

Tags: typescript

I've something like this.

```
$('select').each(function () {
  var x = (this as HTMLSelectElement).value;
  (this as HTMLSelectElement).setSelectionRange(0,0);
  ...
});
```

The jquery definiton file defines `this` would be of the type `HTMLELement`.
Because of the selector I know `this` is of type `HTMLSelectElement`. It would be nice to cast the `this` for the full function to the higher type.
Sure, I can write `var _this = (this as HTMLSelectElement)`. But it is also possible to change the `this` type of the function? Somthing like:

```
$('select').each(function () this as HTMLSelectElement { ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not use `strictFunctionTypes` (or have is explicitly set to false in tsconfig) you can explicitly set the type of the `this` parameter:

```
$('select').each(function (this: HTMLInputElement) {
    var x = this.value;
    this.setSelectionRange(0,0);    
});
```

If not the simplest solution is to use an extra variable

```
$('select').each(function () {
    let local = this as HTMLInputElement;
    var x = local.value;
    local.setSelectionRange(0,0);    
});
```

You could also create a helper function to allow the assignment in spite of `strictFunctionTypes`.

Answer (score 1):

I can’t test it now but this should work:

```
$('select').each(function () {
   var box = this as HTMLSelectElement;
   var x = box.value;
   box.setSelectionRange(0,0);
   ...
});
```